# Directory file list and hyperlinker not hyper linking right

Tags: vba, excel, hyperlink

Hi been working on this for a bit now and I cant seem to figure out why my code is making text look like hyperlinks but not actually linking the correct path.

```
Sub hyperlinker()

  Dim FSO As Object
  Dim rsFSO As Object
  Dim baseFolder As Object
  Dim file As Object
  Dim folder As Object
  Dim row As Integer
  Dim name As String
  Dim path As String


  'Get the current folder
  Set FSO = CreateObject("scripting.filesystemobject")
  Set baseFolder = FSO.GetFolder(ThisWorkbook.path)
  Set FSO = Nothing

  'Get the row at which to insert
  row = Range("A65536").End(xlUp).row + 1

  'Create the recordset for sorting
  Set rsFSO = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
  With rsFSO.Fields
    .Append "path", 200, 200
    .Append "Name", 200, 200
    .Append "Type", 200, 200
  End With
  rsFSO.Open

  ' Traverse the entire folder tree
  TraverseFolderTree baseFolder, baseFolder, rsFSO
  Set baseFolder = Nothing

  'Sort by type and name
  rsFSO.Sort = "Type ASC, Name ASC "
  rsFSO.MoveFirst

  'Populate the first column of the sheet
  While Not rsFSO.EOF
    name = rsFSO("Name").Value
    path = rsFSO("Path").Value
    If (name <> ThisWorkbook.name) Then
      ActiveSheet.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=Cells(row, 1), Address:=path, TextToDisplay:=name
      row = row + 1
    End If
    rsFSO.MoveNext
  Wend

   'Close the recordset
  rsFSO.Close
  Set rsFSO = Nothing

End Sub

Private Sub TraverseFolderTree(ByVal parent As Object, ByVal node As Object, ByRef rs As Object)

  'List all files
  For Each file In node.Files

    Dim name As String
    name = Mid(file.path, Len(parent.path) + 2)

    rs.AddNew
    rs("Path") = path
    rs("Name") = name
    rs("Type") = "FILE"
    rs.Update
  Next

  'List all folders
  For Each folder In node.SubFolders
    TraverseFolderTree parent, folder, rs
  Next

End Sub
```

Help make the hyperlinks actual hyperlinks please.

Comment: Have you checked to make sure that `path` actually contains a string when the hyperlink is set?

Comment: could you be a little more specific, I need to

    `Dim path As String`
    `path = ???`

Comment: actually i figured it out, thank you added `Dim path As String`
    `path = Mid(file.path, Len(parent.path) + 2)` after `dim name as string` that got the hyperlinks to work.
hopefully I don't have anymore issues with this thing =P thank you for your help and pointing me in the right direction!

Answer (score 0):

thank you @ARich

pointed me in the right direction.

hopefully the final code!

```
Sub hyperlinker()

  Dim FSO As Object
  Dim rsFSO As Object
  Dim baseFolder As Object
  Dim file As Object
  Dim folder As Object
  Dim row As Integer
  Dim name As String
  Dim path As String


  'Get the current folder
  Set FSO = CreateObject("scripting.filesystemobject")
  Set baseFolder = FSO.GetFolder(ThisWorkbook.path)
  Set FSO = Nothing

  'Get the row at which to insert
  row = Range("A65536").End(xlUp).row + 1

  'Create the recordset for sorting
  Set rsFSO = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
  With rsFSO.Fields
    .Append "path", 200, 200
    .Append "Name", 200, 200
    .Append "Type", 200, 200
  End With
  rsFSO.Open

  ' Traverse the entire folder tree
  TraverseFolderTree baseFolder, baseFolder, rsFSO
  Set baseFolder = Nothing

  'Sort by type and name
  rsFSO.Sort = "Type ASC, Name ASC "
  rsFSO.MoveFirst

  'Populate the first column of the sheet
  While Not rsFSO.EOF
    name = rsFSO("Name").Value
    path = rsFSO("Path").Value
   If (name <> ThisWorkbook.name) Then
      ActiveSheet.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=Cells(row, 1), Address:=path, TextToDisplay:=name
      row = row + 1
    End If
    rsFSO.MoveNext
  Wend

  'Close the recordset
  rsFSO.Close
  Set rsFSO = Nothing

End Sub

Private Sub TraverseFolderTree(ByVal parent As Object, ByVal node As Object, ByRef rs As Object)

  'List all files
  For Each file In node.Files

    Dim name As String
    name = Mid(file.path, Len(parent.path) + 2)

    Dim path As String
    path = Mid(file.path, Len(parent.path) + 2)

    rs.AddNew
    rs("Path") = path
    rs("Name") = name
    rs("Type") = "FILE"
    rs.Update
  Next

  'List all folders
   For Each folder In node.SubFolders
    TraverseFolderTree parent, folder, rs
  Next


End Sub
```

just added that "Dim path as string" at the end there and it seemed to hook the path in with the hyperlink.